# Why am I getting empty array as I am storing the list into class and then I am storing each class object into array

Tags: java

This is my code

```
package sumit;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class sum1{
       ArrayList<Integer> list=null;
           sum1(ArrayList<Integer> list){
               this.list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            this.list=list;
        }

        public ArrayList<Integer> getList() {
            return this.list;
        }
    }

public class Sk {
    static sum1[] x = new sum1[5];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list0 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list0.add(5);
        list0.add(6);

        sum1 s=new sum1(list0);
        x[0]=s;
        list0.clear();

        list0.add(8);
        list0.add(9);

        sum1 d=new sum1(list0);
        x[1]=d;
        list0.clear();
        System.out.println(x[0].getList());
        System.out.println(x[1].getList());
    }
}
```

I am getting empty array but I've stored the objects into array. Can someone please explain why am I getting such output

```
OUTPUT:
[]
[]
```

I know this is happening because of `list0.clear()` but does't that list is already stored into class as the copy? Why `list0.clear()` affecting the list stored into class?

Comment: You're (1) unnecessarily initializing `list`, (2) creating a new `ArrayList` in the constructor and instantly discarding it, and (3) reusing the same list, which you keep clearing. Perhaps you want `this.list = new ArrayList<>(list)`.

Comment: @chrylis Thankyou sir, It worked, But can you explain to me how as list0 is going as a copy into class so how clearing it affecting the list into the class?

Comment: Hmm? `list0` is *not* copied; that's the entire problem. You have an *aliasing bug*.

Comment: @chrylis So sir this problem only occurs with the list? and are there any other alternative to overcome this bug? By the way, thank you, sir, for you time

Comment: In your code you are not passing the list as such, but a reference to the list, so any changes to list are reflected in you class. Sometimes you might want this behaviour but in does make reasoning about your and debugging more difficult

Comment: @Gavin Oh! Now I noticed thankyou, sir.